# How do I deal with WPF Validation and MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation

I have a WPF page (as my View) in an MVVM model. The View is an entry form with many textboxes. I have a custom ValidationRule built to validate each textbox and display tooltip warnings accordingly. However, I only want the "Commit" button to be enabled when all the validators pass. Right now, my "Commit" button's IsEnabled is bound to the DataContext based on other criteria. How do I add the caveat of "only be enabled when all validators pass" when my IsEnabled is already bound like so?

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsDataLoaded}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Commit button should be bound to a `RelayCommand` in your `ViewModel`, and just set the `CanExecute()` to only be true if `this.IsDataLoaded` and `this.IsValid`

```
CommitCommand = new RelayCommand(
    param => SaveChanges()
    param => this.IsDataLoaded && this.IsValid
);
```

For verifying if the ViewModel is valid or not, I would suggest using [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you bind the Button to a Command, [make the Command implement CanExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute.aspx) so it only returns true when the validations rules validate.

Comment: They are bound to Commands but the validation rules are part of the textbox binding, how would the datacontext be aware of the status of the validators?

Comment: I prefer the ViewModel to be aware of the validity of the data so I do not put validation in the Views/Bindings.

Comment: I agree with Erno, especially if you use Data Annotations for your validation, it makes validation such a simple process and as Erno stated your command CanExecute method can take into consideration the validity of the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with converter you want